# AngularJS: Directive communicating with other other directives via controller API

Tags: angularjs, api, controller, directive

## Child directive communicating with the parent directive

The following code below works perfectly, except when I uncomment the template line in the parent directive (parentD)

```
.directive('parentD', ['$window', function($window) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    controller: function($scope) {
      this.testvar = 'Hello';
      this.doSomething = function() {
        $window.alert("This is an alert from the parent");
        return this.testvar;
      }
    },
    //template: '<h1>Parent Template</h1>'
  }
}])
.directive('childD', ['$window', function($window) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: '^parentD',
    scope: {},
    template: '<h2>Child Template</h2>',
    link: function(scope, element, attribute, controller) {
      $window.alert('The parent passes this message ' + controller.doSomething());
    }
  }
```

It seems to not execute the child directive when this line is uncommented.

http://plnkr.co/edit/h3bMe5mJ0QnbRHIla8l9

Thanks for any help, I'm sure I have made a mistake somewhere, I just need an extra set of eyes on it.

Comment: Need to use "this" keyword as shown in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for replying, your code looks exactly like the one I posted above, could you tell me where the difference is? Did you uncomment the template line in the parent? I think there might have been confusion with my latest plunker not saving, I have updated it to reflect the code in my original post.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/pIkN5Uc3JYQpsbKOMcY1?p=preview please check this link and my whole updated answer. You'll have both working templates and all msgs that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('directiveExample', [])
    .directive('parentD', ['$window', function($window) {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        replace:true,
        transclude: true,
        controller: function($scope) {
          this.testvar = 'Hello';
          this.doSomething = function() {
            $window.alert("This is an alert from the parent");
            return this.testvar;
          }
        },
        template: '<div><h1>Parent Template</h1><div ng-transclude></div></div>'
      }
    }])
    .directive('childD', ['$window', function($window) {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '^parentD',
        replace:true,
        scope: {},
        template: '<div><h2>Child Template</h2></div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attribute, controller) {

          $window.alert('The parent passes this message ' + controller.doSomething());
        }
      }
    }])
})(window.angular);
```

I think you'll understand what I've done.
But feel free to ask any question.
Now check your both templates are working properly.
Here, I have used ng-transclude in parent template to show parent template content as well as child template (with its content) because we have parent-child scenario.

You can check this working link,
http://plnkr.co/edit/pIkN5Uc3JYQpsbKOMcY1?p=preview

Comment: **Perfect**, I did try transclude myself, but I didn't include the ng-transclude in the parent template, which makes sense now. Thanks for your help!